# Multiple maps in one page to be resizable

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I'm developing multiple maps in one page and these maps can be resized. I use goMap to generate google maps, so to resize maps by: 
`google.maps.event.trigger($.goMap.map, 'resize');`
But it just resize the last map, so how to change $.goMap.map to which will be resized?

Or any other solution to resize multiple maps in one page?

Comment: can you not pass in an id selector $("#map").goMap();

Comment: Yes, there has DIV ID passed to goMap().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. That's right. If you really don't want to recall goMap function again, you can create a array to save all maps once map generated.

```
**var mapArray = [];**
$("#map").goMap({
    address: 'USA',
    zoom: 3,
    maptype: 'ROADMAP'
});

mapArray.push($.goMap.map);

var t2 = $("#map2").goMap({
    address: 'Canada',
    zoom: 2,
    maptype: 'ROADMAP'
});
mapArray.push($.goMap.map);

var t3 = $("#map3").goMap({
    address: 'Brasil',
    zoom: 2,
    maptype: 'ROADMAP'
});
mapArray.push($.goMap.map);
```

Then in your following code, you can get your specific map with

```
var map = mapArray[i];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I resolve it, just recall the goMap function before trigger the resize event. It works but  the code looks not so good.